# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'import'

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

i want to draw a graph in networkx by taking a matrix as an input from a folder,however i am getting this error "at line 29 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'import" i am an beginner in python would be really thankful my code is

```
# you can change the target folder here
dir_list =  os.listdir("data")
new_dir_list = []
for s in dir_list:
if s[0]!=".":
    new_dir_list.append(s)
dir_list = new_dir_list


print "The files to be read ", dir_list
graphs = {}
'''
Reading all the files and storing them in a dictionary
'''
for s in dir_list:
    print "Reading", s
    f = open('data/'+s,'r')
    #f = csv.reader(open('data/'+item,'r'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')
    f = csv.reader(open('data/'+s,'r'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')
    lines= list(f)
    g = nx.Graph()
    #g = nx.DiGraph()
    g.add_nodes_from(range(len(lines)))

    for row in range(len(lines)):
        for col in range(len(lines)):
           if int(lines[row][col]) == 1:
                g.add_edge(row,col) 
    print "Done reading all the files"  
    graphs[s] = g 
nx.draw(g)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: the value in lines[row][col] seems to be "import", you're reading all the files in a directory, maybe one of those files is a .py file.

Comment: Do your CSV files contain square matrices with 0 or 1 (or any other integer) as each element? If no, then this code won't work. The element at `lines[row][column]` is not an integer. Hence the error.

Comment: @zardosht yeah my csv file contain square matrix with either 0 or 1 as each elememnt. how to reslove this error??

Comment: this is the error im getting:
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[0'

Answer (score 0):

The errors "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'import'" and "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[0'" are basically saying the same thing.

The value that you are giving to the int() function - in the former case the 'import', in the latter case the '[[0' - cannot be converted to an integer. Because it is obviously not an *integer literal*.

The problem is in the content of some of your files. As Rafael Barros is saying, maybe one of the files in your directory is a .py file. I would print the file name, and the row and column of the lines in the loop. This way you can find the file and position that causes the problem.

See [documentation of int() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) for further info.